# I'm trying to get two images to float side by side

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.fruit {
  width: 1200px;
  max-height: 39em;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit">

  <img src="images/OrangesPinkBackground.jpg" alt=" " width="600px" />

  <img src="images/GrapefruitPinkBackground.jpg" alt=" " width="600px" />

</div>
```

I've tried so many different things I can think of and they just keep ending up like this

[image]

Maybe it's a problem with how I have the body styled? because there is a lot more whitespace on the right side where the scroll bar is. What I was trying to was evenly split the two images so they would each take up half the screen and only extend about 40em downwards as well. Somehow I just can't get them to lineup right.

I'll take any suggestions at this point.

Comment: likely the issue is the `width="600px"` to my knowledge the width HTML attributes don't take units. Try it without the `px` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: odd, I just tried it in the snippet editor and it worked just fine

Comment: probably the whitespace causing width to be greater. Better options than float to align things.

Comment: even in the snippet I edited into your answer right now i see the image placeholders together in a line?

Comment: What is wrong with the images in the screenshot?

Comment: maybe it's that they're not aligned. Could set the heights explicitly, or just have the right image cropped to match the height.

Comment: yeah I got them aligned okay now, though I ended up just setting width to 50% for each and that worked, I also fixed the whitespace on the right hand side. The only issue I'm having now is the picture with the oranges is too long and I have both pictures inside a div with defined width and height and even if I set the images to object-fit:contain; it still doesn't have an affect. I'm very puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="fruit">
  <div class="fruit-img"> 
     <img src="images/OrangesPinkBackground.jpg" alt=" "/>
  </div>
  <div class="fruit-img">
     <img src="images/GrapefruitPinkBackground.jpg" alt=" "/>
  </div>

</div>
```

In your parent fruit class:

```
.fruit{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
height: 39em;
width: 100%;
}
```

In your child fruit class for each image, this acts as a container

```
.fruit-img{
height: 100%;
flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

This is your actual image class

```
.fruit-img img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%:
}
```

Comment: beat me to it. I'd maybe add in about why you're using flex for this use case since the OP seems relatively new as of writing this.

Comment: flex is relatively easy to understand (compared to other css properties) and extremely powerful. it's worth learning as soon as possible.

Comment: Awesome, I don't really understand what the flex stuff is if you don't mind clarifying? We only learned the basic stuff, but I like to reach on my projects because it leads me to other people and I learn extra things outside of class too. If not no worries, I can always google!

Comment: Flex is a powerful property in CSS which lets you create one dimensional layouts. It's hard to explain over comments, but basically, when you set a parent element to display: flex, this makes all the child elements stack next to each other. You can also have them stack vertically, by changing the flex direction: flex-direction: column. With these 2 commands we easily replaced float.

Comment: Great, that makes sense. I'm assuming I would've learned it at some point but hey. I know what I'm doing tonight, watching videos on Flex.

Comment: it's definitely worth learning & having it under your toolbelt, especially if you want to stick with web development after college. good luck with everything

Comment: a good introductory link to flexbox can be found https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @RyanMatthews Please mark it as the answer if it has helped you provide a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. It's more easy than using float.

Use flex with:

```
justify-content: space-between
```

to get images align at the end of screen on each side